# Display a string in console

Tags: java

I want to display a string in the eclipse console using `Sytem.out.println()`.

Here is the string which I want to display: `String ch : Le mot est = "Bonjour"`

I am willing to keep the word `Bonjour` between the 2 sides.

Comment: 2 sides? you mean quotation marks? so ... what is your problem? what did you try? what (doesn't) work?

Comment: `String ch = "Le mot est = \"Bonjour\""; System.out.println(ch);`

Comment: sidgate, you forgot a " to close the String

Comment: yes quotation marks..when i defined the variable ch, i have an error (String ch = Le mot est = "Bonjour";) How to declare this variable ch please with the whole sentence?

Comment: @josef read the above remarks

Comment: @sidgate thanks i tried with String ch = "Le mot est = \"Bonjour\"";  and it works well..thanks a lot

Comment: @Stultuske thanks, i solved the problem with response of Sidgate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String ch = "Le mot est = \"Bonjour\""; 
System.out.println(ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
System.out.println( "String ch : Le mot est = \"Bonjour\"");
```

Comment: Sorry because I explained the problem, but finally I wanted something like that: String ch = "Le mot est = \"Bonjour\""; and now is resolved..thank you